Restore access to DB from bookmarked URL in SwiftUI
I have the following code to bookmark URLs for future access:
 private func checkForSQLiteFiles(at containerURL: URL, appName: String) {
    do {
            viewModel.connect(strConnect: selectedSQLiteFile!.path)
            viewModel.fetchAllTables()
            
            // Save selected SQLite file to UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedSQLiteFile, forKey: "selectedSQLiteFile")
            saveBookmark(for: selectedSQLiteFile!, key: "SQLiteBookmark")
        }
    } catch {
        errorMessages.append("Error")
    }
}


func saveBookmark(for url: URL, key: String) {
    do {
        let bookmarkData = try url.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(bookmarkData, forKey: key)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create bookmark for \(url.path): \(error)")
    }
}

The code above works fine. BTW I'm getting access using NSOpenPanel to files/directories that I selected.
In another place, I have code to restore URLs from bookmarks, try to connect, and request DB again using the same file I used before.
private func openExistingProject() {
    if let sqliteURL = resolveBookmark(for: "SQLiteBookmark") {
        if sqliteURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            // Check if file is readable and exists
            if FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: sqliteURL.path) {
                print("SQLite file is readable at path: \(sqliteURL.path)")
                
                // Proceed to connect and load entities
                viewModel.connect(strConnect: sqliteURL.path)
                viewModel.fetchAllTables()
            } else {
                print("Failed to access the SQLite file at \(sqliteURL.path)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to access the security-scoped resource for \(sqliteURL.path)")
        }
        
        defer { sqliteURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
    } else {
        print("No valid bookmark for SQLite file")
    }
}

func resolveBookmark(for key: String) -> URL? {
    if let bookmarkData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key) {
        var isStale = false
        do {
            let url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
            if isStale {
                print("Bookmark data is stale for \(url.path)")
            }
            return url
        } catch {
            print("Failed to resolve bookmark for key \(key): \(error)")
        }
    }
    return nil
}

But when I call fetchAllTables() in ViewModel:
class SQLiteEntityManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isConnected: Bool = false
    private var db: Connection?
    
    func connect(strConnect: String) {
        // Define the path to the SQLite database file
        let dbPath = strConnect
        
        // Create a connection to the database
        do {
            db = try Connection(dbPath)
            isConnected = true
        } catch {
            print("Unable to open database. Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAllTables() -> [String] {
        guard let db = db else {
            print("Database is not connected")
            return []
        }
        
        do {
            let tables = try db.prepare("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
            return tables.map { "\($0[0]!)" }
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching tables: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
}

it fails with "Error fetching tables: access denied (code:23)". But it still connects successfully without any issues to that DB using that bookmarked URL.
Error happens only when I try to do db.prepare(".....").
Any advices would be appreciated

You're probably getting blocked by the sandbox. Where are you trying to read/write to in the filesystem?

@user20325868 yes, I'm trying to read/write from my other sandboxed app. But I can do that if I ask to open that directory via NSOpenPanel. I was just wondering why bookmarks don't work in that case as they are supposed to keep permissions to directory/files

Take a look at this it may help you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/discovering-and-diagnosing-app-sandbox-violations

Try to check race condition issue, I think you should call fetchAllTables() only after establishing the connection
as an quick test you can try to call func fetchAllTables() just after db = try Connection(dbPath)

I already do so in checkForSQLiteFiles method. Even if I place call of fetchAllTables() right after db = try Connection(dbPath) issue still exists
